# Is the logarithm function injective (one-to-one)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is the logarithm function injective (or, one-to-one)?

In other words, does $\log_2(x) = \log_2(y) \implies x = y$?

I.e., as $x$ and $y$ are in the same log base, can I just drop the logs?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does $\log _b \left( x \right) = \log _b \left( y \right) \rightarrow x = y$ ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/does-log-b-left-x-right-log-b-left-y-right-rightarrow-x-y)

Comment: You asked a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/does-log-b-left-x-right-log-b-left-y-right-rightarrow-x-y) of which this is clearly a special case in February.  Is there something that wasn't cleared up by the answers there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean for a number $a$ to be equal to $\log_2(x)$? It means that $2^a=x$.

Can you use this to answer the question?

Comment: Ah yes thank you, so $2^a = x = y$ hence $x = y$ correct?

Comment: More like $2^a = 2^b$ and thus $2^{a-b} = 1$.

Comment: More like $a=b$ and thus $2^a=2^b$.